# How do I remove the dot using isDot() using RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

Tags: php

I have this simple below code to help me get the contents of all files and sub folder.  I took this code from the PHP cook book. it says that I can use the isDot() but it doesn't explain how to ..

I tried to put a if just before array but it doesn't work...

```
if (! $file->isDot())
```

I don't know how to put both getPathname and isDot when adding to the array.

I've read the PHP net website but don't understand how to fit in.

code:

```
$dir  =  new  RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/usr/local'); 

$dircontent = array();
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $file) {

$dircontent [] = $file -> getPathname();

}
print_r($dircontent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag in your `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to get rid of dot files:

```
$dir    = '/usr/local';
$result = array();
$files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
        $dir,
        FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    )
);


foreach ($files as $file) {
    $result[] = $file->getPathname();
}

print_r($result);
```

The reason `isDot()` is failing is that your `$file` variable holds a `SplFileInfo` object, not a `DirectoryIterator`.

Comment: Hi  ... thank you so much .....   ok you have made a slight change to my code.

$files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)

so what does it actually mean by putting this like  RecursiveIteratorIterator and FilesystemIterator  methods into a variable?

thanks once again

Comment: @BlissfulSnake That's just a code style choice, not an actual change. My code is equivalent to yours.

Comment: hi ....  i see .. ok thanks .. but i noticed that the folder are no longer displaying. it shows foldername with filename but the actual folder by itself into its own array is missing.